# How to integrate 3rd party merchant payment gateway in ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I've been looking for 2 days on how to integrate my merchant payment gateway into ubercart with no lack. So I decided to ask it here.

I have the following code as an example from my merchant:

```
<form name="payFormCcard" method="post" action=" https://test.MyMerchantGateway.com/ECN/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="merchantId" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3000.0" >
<input type="hidden" name="orderRef" value="000000000014">
<input type="hidden" name="currCode" value="608" >
<input type="hidden" name="successUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Success.html">
<input type="hidden" name="failUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Fail.html">
<input type="hidden" name="cancelUrl" value="http://www.yourdomain.com/Cancel.html">
<input type="hidden" name="payType" value="N">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Please note that I change the actual domain above for security reason.

What I want after checkout is redirect it to https://test.MyMerchantGateway.com/ECN/eng/payment/payForm.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to do an off-site payment (external to your Drupal site), so in your payment module, you will need to write a payment method that redirects like so:

```
function my_pay_gateway_uc_payment_method() {
  $methods[] = array(
    'id' => 'my_pay_credit',
    'name' => t('My Payment Gateway'),
    'title' => t('My Payment Gateway'),
    'desc' => t('Pay through my payment gateway'),
    'callback' => 'my_payment_method',
    'redirect' => 'my_payment_form',  // <-- Note the redirect callback provided
    'weight' => 1,
    'checkout' => TRUE,
  );
  return $methods;
}
```

Then you should add code to the redirect callback to build a form that sits behind the *Submit Order* button to redirect to your payment gateway while including all the information you need like:

```
function my_payment_form($form, &$form_state, $order) {

  // Build the data to send to my payment gateway
  $data = array(
    'merchantId' => '1',
    'amount' => '3000.0',
    'orderRef' => '000000000014',
    'currCode' => '608',
    // You can fill in the rest...
  );

  // This code goes behind the final checkout button of the checkout pane
  foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) {
      $form[$name] = array('#type' => 'hidden', '#value' => $value);
    }
  }

  $form['#action'] = 'https://test.MyMerchantGateway.com/ECN/eng/payment/payForm.jsp';
  $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
  $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit Orders'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

For more details, see my blog post at http://nmc-codes.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-ubercart-payment.html

Comment: Thank you nmc. I had successfully implement your code. Regarding about $form['#action'] = 'https://test.MyMerchantGateway.com/ECN/eng/payment/payForm.jsp'; I addd to add some value add URL. Example: https://test.MyMerchantGateway.com?id=111, name="ex....... All these value are already appear at review page. May I know how to get these value? Here is my related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348089/array-how-to-retrieve-value