# Array - How to retrieve value

Tags: php, arrays

Example 1:

```
$string = stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 25 )
$result= $string->product_id
```

$result will get 25

Example 2:

```
$string = Array ( [30] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 44 ))
$result= $string[30]->product_id
```

$result will get 44

How about this one? I want to retrieve first name.

```
$string = [addresses] => Array ( [shipping] => 

AddressesAddress Object ( 
       [addressBook:AddressesAddress:private] => AddressesAddressBook  Object ( 
          [performanceHint:AddressesAddressBook:private] => 1 
          [uid:AddressesAddressBook:private] => 1
          [addresses:AddressesAddressBook:private] => Array ( 
             [-1] => AddressesAddress Object *RECURSION* 
             [-8] => AddressesAddress Object ( 
                 [addressBook:AddressesAddress:private] => AddressesAddressBook               Object *RECURSION* 
                [schemaAddress:AddressesSchemaAddress:private] => stdClass Object ( 
                [first_name] => Sir))))
```

I only know this:

```
$result= $string["shipping"]
```

and the result is

```
AddressesAddress Object ( 
   [addressBook:AddressesAddress:private] => AddressesAddressBook  Object ( 
      [performanceHint:AddressesAddressBook:private] => 1 
      [uid:AddressesAddressBook:private] => 1
      [addresses:AddressesAddressBook:private] => Array ( 
         [-1] => AddressesAddress Object *RECURSION* 
         [-8] => AddressesAddress Object ( 
             [addressBook:AddressesAddress:private] => AddressesAddressBook               Object *RECURSION* 
            [schemaAddress:AddressesSchemaAddress:private] => stdClass Object ( 
            [first_name] => Sir))))
```

I need help.

Comment: Have you tried `$result= $string["shipping"]["addressBook"]["addresses"]["-8"]["schemaAddress"]["first_name"];`?

Comment: What about `=====>` `[addresses] => Array ( [shipping] =>` within your `$string` that won't make a valid array

Comment: @Sean, I tried. No result.

Comment: @Uchiha, I dun get what you mean....

Comment: I had tried this $result =  print_r($customer_particular["shipping"], true); print_r($result["addressBook:AddressesAddress"]);.........Result is "U" What the.......zzzzzz

Comment: can you look into the class `AddressesAddressBook` it may have some setter and getter method

Comment: @ChetanAmeta, I dun think there is.......